# When i append div on document ready, my div text not changed.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, swipe

im using thebird swipe example, just removing static div in thebird swipe example and append dynamic div on document ready but my default style like data-index, transition-duration, transform is not applying

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Swiper demo</title>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://idangero.us/swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<style>body{background:#eee;font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#000;margin:0;padding:0;}.swiper-container{width:500px;height:300px;margin:20px auto;}.swiper-slide{text-align:center;font-size:18px;background:#fff;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:-webkit-flex;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;-webkit-justify-content:center;justify-content:center;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;-webkit-align-items:center;align-items:center;}</style>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="swiper-container">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">

</div>
</div>
 
<script src="http://idangero.us/swiper/dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
 
 <script>
 
  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container');
    
  $(document).ready(function(e){
   for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.className = 'swiper-slide';
    element.innerHTML = 'slide '+i;
    $('.swiper-wrapper').append(element);
   }
   var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container');    
 
  });
 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where is your style.css? and swipe.js

Comment: @HTCom Thanks for response. now  i put style.css and swipe.js code in my question. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use stackoverflow code snippet to make version that more easily test? Your code is not full. For example, html code. I cannot see closing tags of body, html...

Comment: @HTCom See snippet, just remove static div slide and append dynamic div.

Comment: @HTCom Now This is my example.if div is static working properly but append div then my style is not applying.

Comment: @HTCom Your code is not useful. please in this code just remove static div and append dynamic div on document ready like $('.swipe-wrap').append('<div><b>Abc</b></div>'); and refresh a page

Comment: What is difference?  `$(document).ready(function(e){
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
   $('.swiper-wrapper').append('<div class=\'swiper-slide\'><b>Abc '+i+'</b></div>');
  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container');
  
 });` Both work as same. Divs were added dynamically.

Comment: @HTCom your code is working that example. but above question i need to do dynamic code.

Comment: Can you talk more the "dynamic"? In this, I use script to append new div => that is dynamic too.

Comment: @HTCom i use this code because, //select all from Recent                                                         
 function populateDB(tx){
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Recent GROUP BY SearchTerm',[],querySuccess,errorCB);
 }
 
 function querySuccess(tx,result){  
  $.each(result.rows,function(index){
   var row = result.rows.item(index);
   $('.swipe-wrap').append('<div><b>'+row["SearchTerm"]+'</b></div>');
  });  
 }

Comment: @HTCom i need dynamic code for above question. Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have the sql here, and I don't know your data structure, so I cannot help you more. Sorry. but for your case, it's very simple. You just use PHP to write data by syntax `<?php for.... echo ''<div class='swiper-slide'><b>Abc</b></div>";?>

Comment: @HTCom The answerd you have given if swipeleft i need next div text alert and swiperight i need previous div text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145265/discussion-between-k-series-and-htcom).

Answer (score 0):

Here is for detecting prev/next

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
        $('.swiper-wrapper').append('<div class=\'swiper-slide\'><b>Abc '+i+'</b></div>');
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container');

    swiper.on('onSlideNextStart', function(e){
        alert('next');
    });
    swiper.on('onSlidePrevStart', function(e){
        alert('back');
    });
});
```

Did you read documentation of this library? Please read it carefully http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WSlw5miGPSF

Comment: in this code through when i swipeleft/swiperight i need that prev/next div text alert.

Comment: if swipeleft i need next div text alert and swiperight i need previous div text.